# Get DOS path instead of Windows path

Tags: windows, command-line

In a Windows CMD.exe command line, how can I get the full DOS name/short name (a.k.a. 8.3 format) of the directory I am in?

For example, if I am in the directory `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_22`, I want to display it's short name `C:\PROGRA~1\Java\JDK16~1.0_2`.

I know running `dir /x` will give me the short names of files/directories in the current directory but I haven't been able to find a way to display the full path of the current directory in short name format. I'm having to work my way through the path from the root, directory by directory, running `dir /x` in each.

I'm sure there is an easier way to do this?

Comment: What's wrong with asking it here? There are hundreds of questions tagged with DOS or MS-DOS.

Comment: Perhaps they are programming questions related to DOS or MS_DOS?

Comment: There are thousands of questions tagged email or video, but this is still not the place to ask about for example how to attach a video to an email...

Comment: I think it's a perfectly valid question to ask and I don't appreciate the down vote.

Comment: I'm glad it was asked on here - the answer below helped me out.

Answer (score 173, accepted):

```
for %I in (.) do echo %~sI
```

Any simpler way?

Comment: Okay but how to have it include directory names?

Comment: Found my answer: `for /d %I in (*) do @echo %~sI`  Every path segment is short, great. Trouble wasn't directly with the long names, nor even spaces though a pain, but worst is when international characters are present which simply hose my script taking this dir list as input.

Comment: If you're calling this from a batch script you have to escape the `%` signs: `for %%I in ("C:\folder with spaces") do echo %%~sI`

Comment: What about SET ABC=c:\long path with spaces\aaa\bbb   to the short version ?

Comment: @Timbo Simple enough! Thank you! The main drive was running low on disk space.

Comment: This only works when: 1) 8dot3names explicitly enabled for the drive: `fsutil 8dot3name set` 2) A file or a directory created after the feature enabled otherwise 3) the short name must be set for a file or a directory explicitly: `fsutil file setshortname`. So, the one liner is just not enough.

Answer (score 45):

You could also enter the following into a CMD window:

```
dir <ParentDirectory> /X
```

Where `<ParentDirectory>` is replaced with the full path of the directory containing the item you would like the name for.

While the output is not a simple as [Timbo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4051190/641833), it will list all the items in the specified directory with the actual name and (if different) the short name.

If you do use `for %I in (.) do echo %~sI` you can replace the `.` with the full path of the file/folder to get the short name of that file/folder (otherwise the short name of the current folder is returned).

Tested on Windows 7 x64.

Answer (score 33):

In windows batch scripts, [`%~s1` expands path parameters to short names](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/for). Create this batch file:

```
@ECHO OFF
echo %~s1
```

I called mine `shortNamePath.cmd` and call it like this:

```
c:\>shortNamePath "c:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk"
c:\PROGRA~2\Android\ANDROI~1
```

**Edit:** here's a version that uses the current directory if no parameter was supplied:

```
@ECHO OFF
if '%1'=='' (%0 .) else echo %~s1
```

Called without parameters:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk>shortNamePath
C:\PROGRA~2\Android\ANDROI~1
```

Comment: A meticulous way to produce an utility for future use. I couldn't thank you enough for this solution. Calling such command anytime effortlessly is a bless.

Comment: In case another noob comes across this clever solution: The script checks if the first parameter is empty. If so, the script runs itself again, but this time with the current directory as the first argument (`%0` is the pathname of the batch script).

Answer (score 11):

Being a programmer made this 10-minute Winform project. It's been useful for me. Making this app to a context menu for file explorer would save more clicks.

[image: 10-minute application]

Form1.cs:

```cs
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace ToShortPath
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        public static extern int GetShortPathName(
                 [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPTStr)]
                   string path,
                 [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPTStr)]
                   StringBuilder shortPath,
                 int shortPathLength
                 );
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Show the dialog and get result.
            var openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();
            DialogResult result = openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
            if (result == DialogResult.OK) // Test result.
            {
                textBox1.Text = openFileDialog1.FileName;
            }
        }
        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var openFileDialog1 = new FolderBrowserDialog();
            DialogResult result = openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
            if (result == DialogResult.OK) // Test result.
            {
                textBox1.Text = openFileDialog1.SelectedPath;
            }

        }

        private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            StringBuilder shortPath = new StringBuilder(65000);
            GetShortPathName(textBox1.Text, shortPath, shortPath.Capacity);
            textBox2.Text = shortPath.ToString();
        }

    }
}
```

Form1.Designer.cs:

```cs
namespace ToShortPath
{
    partial class Form1
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Required designer variable.
        /// </summary>
        private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

        /// <summary>
        /// Clean up any resources being used.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing && (components != null))
            {
                components.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

        #region Windows Form Designer generated code

        /// <summary>
        /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
        /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            this.textBox1 = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
            this.textBox2 = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
            this.label1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
            this.label2 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
            this.button1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
            this.button2 = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
            this.SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // textBox1
            // 
            this.textBox1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(69, 13);
            this.textBox1.Multiline = true;
            this.textBox1.Name = "textBox1";
            this.textBox1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(516, 53);
            this.textBox1.TabIndex = 0;
            this.textBox1.TextChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.textBox1_TextChanged);
            // 
            // textBox2
            // 
            this.textBox2.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(69, 72);
            this.textBox2.Multiline = true;
            this.textBox2.Name = "textBox2";
            this.textBox2.ReadOnly = true;
            this.textBox2.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(516, 53);
            this.textBox2.TabIndex = 1;
            // 
            // label1
            // 
            this.label1.AutoSize = true;
            this.label1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(7, 35);
            this.label1.Name = "label1";
            this.label1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(56, 13);
            this.label1.TabIndex = 2;
            this.label1.Text = "Long Path";
            // 
            // label2
            // 
            this.label2.AutoSize = true;
            this.label2.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(7, 95);
            this.label2.Name = "label2";
            this.label2.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(57, 13);
            this.label2.TabIndex = 3;
            this.label2.Text = "Short Path";
            // 
            // button1
            // 
            this.button1.AutoSize = true;
            this.button1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(591, 13);
            this.button1.Name = "button1";
            this.button1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(40, 53);
            this.button1.TabIndex = 4;
            this.button1.Text = "File";
            this.button1.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            this.button1.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.button1_Click);
            // 
            // button2
            // 
            this.button2.AutoSize = true;
            this.button2.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(637, 12);
            this.button2.Name = "button2";
            this.button2.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(46, 53);
            this.button2.TabIndex = 5;
            this.button2.Text = "Folder";
            this.button2.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            this.button2.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.button2_Click);
            // 
            // Form1
            // 
            this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
            this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
            this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(687, 135);
            this.Controls.Add(this.button2);
            this.Controls.Add(this.button1);
            this.Controls.Add(this.label2);
            this.Controls.Add(this.label1);
            this.Controls.Add(this.textBox2);
            this.Controls.Add(this.textBox1);
            this.Name = "Form1";
            this.Text = "Short Path";
            this.ResumeLayout(false);
            this.PerformLayout();

        }

        #endregion

        private System.Windows.Forms.TextBox textBox1;
        private System.Windows.Forms.TextBox textBox2;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Label label1;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Label label2;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Button button1;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Button button2;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is overkill of anyone wanting to work from the command line. But I like for C# programs.

Comment: MSDN page for api: [GetShortPathName](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364989.aspx)

Answer (score 6):

run `cmd.exe` and do the following:

```
> cd "long path name"
> command
```

Then command.com will come up and display only short paths.

[source](http://answers.google.com/answers/threadview/id/522710.html)

Comment: Windows 7 does not have command.com, at least not in the x64 version.

Comment: The above works on Win7 32bit - I just did it. But you're right, it doesn't work on 64bit (also tested).

Comment: neither on windows 8 64bit

Answer (score 5):

Kimbo's answer is perfect for normal files.

```
for %I in (.) do echo %~sI
```

## For MsDos file names on HardLinks

The hard links created with `mklink /H <link> <target>` will not have an MsDos short file name.

In case you `dir /X` and you discover that missing short name you should expect the followings:

```
d:\personal\photos-tofix\2013-proposed1-bad>dir /X
 Volume in drive D has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is 7C7E-04BA

 Directory of d:\personal\photos-tofix\2013-proposed1-bad

03/02/2015  15:15    <DIR>                       .
03/02/2015  15:15    <DIR>                       ..
22/12/2013  12:10         1,948,654 2013-1~1.JPG 2013-12-22--12-10-42------Bulevardul-Petrochimiștilor.jpg
22/12/2013  12:10         1,899,739              2013-12-22--12-10-52------Bulevardul Petrochimiștilor.jpg
```

### Normal file

In this case

```
> for %I in ("2013-12-22--12-10-42------Bulevardul-Petrochimiștilor.jpg") do echo %~sI
```

I've got what I expected

```
d:\personal\PH124E~1\2013-P~3\2013-1~1.JPG
```

### Hard link file

In this case

```
> for %I in ("2013-12-22--12-10-52------Bulevardul-Petrochimiștilor.jpg") do echo %~sI
```

I've got the normal MsDos path but the normal filename.

```
d:\personal\PH124E~1\2013-P~3\2013-12-22--12-10-52------Bulevardul-Petrochimiștilor.jpg`
```

Answer (score 2):

A someone more direct answer is to fix the bug.

%SPARK_HOME%\bin\spark-class2.cmd; Line 54
`Broken: set RUNNER="%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java"`
`Windows Style: set "RUNNER=%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java"`

Otherwise, the RUNNER ends up with quotes, and the command
`"%RUNNER%" -Xmx128m ...`
ends up with double-quotes.  The result is that the Program and File are treated as separate parameters.

Answer (score 1):

similar to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21786312/4459336) but uses a sub-routine

```
@echo off
CLS

:: my code goes here
set "my_variable=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office"

echo %my_variable%

call :_sub_Short_Path "%my_variable%"
set "my_variable=%_s_Short_Path%"

echo %my_variable%

:: rest of my code goes here
goto EOF

:_sub_Short_Path
set _s_Short_Path=%~s1
EXIT /b

:EOF
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$fso = New-Object -com scripting.filesystemobject
$fso.GetFolder('c:\Program Files (x86)').ShortName()

PROGRA~2
```

[Inspired by Dr. Scripto's answer](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/use-powershell-to-display-short-file-and-folder-names/)

Answer (score 1):

if via a batch file use:

```
set SHORT_DIR=%~dsp0%
```

you can use the echo command to check:

```
echo %SHORT_DIR%
```

Answer (score 0):

Place this script somewhere in the windows path. I called mine `getshort.bat` and placed it in the System32 folder.

To use this you must pass a single path parameter after calling the scrip in cmd.exe window.

So open cmd.exe and type something like `getshort.bat "C:\folder\file name with spaces.ext"` You must double-quote paths with spaces otherwise not necessary.

The script will take the path you supplied and store the shortname in a temporary text file with two versions, version 1 has quotes around the short path, and the other version does not.

I use notepad++ to open txt files so if you do not use that program you need to change the line `START "" /MAX NOTEPAD++ "%TMP%\Test.txt"` and replace `notepad++` with your editor's name.

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEEXTENSIONS ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
COLOR 0A

:----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

REM SET THE CD VARIABLE EQUAL TO THE FIRST PARAMATER YOU PASSED THE SCRIPT
:: ..WHICH WAS A FILE PATH OF YOUR CHOOSING...
CD=%1

:----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

:: DELETE ANY LEFTOVERS FROM PRIOR RUNS
IF EXIST "%TMP%\Test.txt" DEL /F /Q "%TMP%\Test.txt"

:----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

:: USE THE FOR COMMAND TO CALL A SUBROUTINE TO STORE THE SHORT NAMES WITH AND WITHOUT QUOTES
FOR %%1 IN ("%CD%") DO (
    SET ARG1="%%~s1"
    SET ARG2=%%~s1
    CALL :CREATE_TXTFILE ARG1 ARG2
    START "" /MAX NOTEPAD++ "%TMP%\Test.txt"
    GOTO :EOF
)

:----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

REM USE THIS SUB-ROUTINE TO STORE THE SHORTNAMES INSIDE THE A TXT FILE
:CREATE_TXTFILE
(
ECHO %ARG1%
ECHO %ARG2%
)>"%TMP%\Test.txt"
:: THE NEXT LINE WILL RETURN THE SCRIPT TO THE LINE BELOW THE CALL COMMAND ABOVE AND CONTINUE EXECUUTION AS NORMAL
:: NOTEPAD++ WILL ATTEMPT TO FIND AND OPEN THE NEWLY CREATED TXT FILE WITH THE SHORTNAMES INSIDE
:: CHANGE TO WHATEVER TEXT EDITOR YOU HAVE TO OPEN TXT FILES IF YOU DONT HAVE NOTEPAD++
EXIT /B
```

Answer (score -4):

use this link, it will automatically convert any path you give to any format
https://pathconverter-pp.azurewebsites.net