# Squared² Character in file path for Jscript launch

Tags: javascript, jscript

I have a site within a corporate portal (fully secure) that launches several applications tied to a certain business group. The problem I am having is one of the file paths I need to Launch has a ² in the path. This software is installed on more than 3000 computers across the globe, so changing the path inst very functional. Here is the snippet of code I am using:

```
<a href="javascript:LaunchApp1()">MC2 / ICE</a>

<script>

      function LaunchApp1() {
         if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf("WOW64") != -1 || 
            navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Win64") != -1 ){
            var ws = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
            ws.Exec('"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\MC² Software\\ice.exe"');
         }
         else {
           var ws = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
           ws.Exec("C:\\Program Files\\MC² Software\\ice.exe");
         }
      }

</script>
```

Any ideas on how to get around the squared character? Have extensively search everywhere.

Thanks!

Comment: `C:\\Program Files\\MCSOFT~1\\ice.exe` .. What is wrong with the `²` character anyway? You have different locales which aren't in unicode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/b2/index.htm

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Values,_variables,_and_literals

looks like you may be able to get away with using a unicode replacement for your squared value, so it would look something like this for your path:

```
ws.Exec('"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\MC\u00B2 Software\\ice.exe"');
```

Comment: Both of these examples worked great. Thanks for the help. The only issue I deal with now is the error saying the operation requires elevation. But this only happens on a few machines.

Comment: This would probably be worthy of a second question being opened.  Unfortunately I don't know of any good way to force it to be ran as admin via a shell command.  Glad I was able to help at least with most of the issue though.

Answer (score 0):

How about using the [short filename](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/8.3_filename) instead? You should be able to convert the whole path to an MS-DOS-compatible path, which shouldn't include the pesky superscript 2, and use that instead. Theres another stackoverflow question asking [how to convert a full path to a short path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4051088/how-to-get-dos-path-instead-of-windows-path), and the simplest answer seems to be to run this in a `cmd` terminal in the directory in question:

```
for /d %I in (*) do @echo %~sI
```

[The Microsoft support site also covers this topic.](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/142982)

Converting the directory name in question to the short form should yield this path:

```
C:\Program Files\MCSOFT~1\ice.exe
```

or

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\MCSOFT~1\ice.exe
```

Comment: This worked as well. Any idea on how I get around the error of "the requested operation requires elevation"? Since we are in a corporate environment, I don't think users will have access to change and UAC controls. Thanks again for the answer.

Comment: @pjparks - I don't really do scripting on Windows, so I have no idea. You should probably post that as another question though (or search for an already existing question).