# Passing a path that contains spaces and parentheses to MATLAB from the terminal/bash

Tags: bash, matlab

I am currently writing a script where I have to call MATLAB from the Terminal and pass it a path argument that contains lousy characters.

As expected, I am running into trouble when the path contains spaces / parentheses. Here is a minimal example to illustrate the issue:

> matlabcmd="/Applications/MATLAB_R2014b.app/bin/matlab -nodesktop
>   -nosplash" run_dir="Users/Me/My Directory With Spaces (and parentheses)/" $matlabcmd -r "addpath('${run_dir}'),exit"

Some things that I have tried:

1. Different combinations of double-quotes and single-quotes in the commands above (this usually fails at calling MATLAB).
2. Using an escape character so that `run_dir="Users/Me/My Directory\ With\ Spaces\ \(and parentheses\)/"` (this manages to call MATLAB, but then MATLAB gets confused by the spaces... and `addpath` does not work).

Is there hope?

Comment: Don't try to use a string for the command to execute. It always ends in pain. See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050

Comment: It could help to use the DOS path like "Users/Me/MyDire~1/", follow e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4051088/how-to-get-dos-path-instead-of-windows-path

Answer (score 0):

Try

> matlabcmd="/Applications/MATLAB_R2014b.app/bin/matlab -nodesktop
>   -nosplash" run_dir="Users/Me/My Directory With Spaces (and parentheses)/" $matlabcmd -r "addpath(getenv('run_dir')),exit"

This will prevent the quoting/escaping nightmare and should lead to the desired effect.