# Native messaging (firefox) host path contains space

Tags: firefox, path, firefox-addon, registry, chrome-native-messaging

I'm having this problem with native messaging (**Firefox**):
If my path to the native manifest (in the windows registry) json contains spaces

e.g. `C:\src\Java Signing Addon\Setup\bin\native_manifest.json`

then I get the familiar error you would get if using such path in windows cmd:

`stderr output from native app lt.dlx.sign: 'C:\src\Java' is not recognized as an internal or external command`

The same path works perfectly fine with **Chrome**

Now, if I wrap the path with double quotes, I get a different error:

`"Win error 123 during operation open on file C:\src\Java Signing Addon\Setup\bin\native_manifest.json" (The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.)`

Did a lot of googling, but nothing :/

Comment: Could you post the content of `native_manifest.json`?

Comment: `{
  "name": "lt.dlx.sign",
  "description": "Test",
  "path": "run.bat",
  "type": "stdio",
  "allowed_extensions": [ "sign@doclogix.com" ]
}`


and the run.bat


`@echo off
java -cp "%~dp0/SignatureApplet.jar" <mainclass> %*`

The same is used in Chrome, which works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to add the window short name for the directory.

To discover it run the command dir /x . If you are adding it from a .bat you can use %~sdp0 to get the current path in a short form.

Also check this [how to get DOS path instead of Windows path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4051088/how-to-get-dos-path-instead-of-windows-path)

Comment: yep, that's the only solution I came up with as well.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue on Windows Firefox 50. Here is a bug for it https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1323148