# Spaces in file paths for puppet on Windows

Tags: windows, file, path, puppet

I need to install some product using Puppet on Windows. I use exec recource

```
exec { 'install':
            command => 'C:\\windows\system32\cmd.exe /c "c:\\Program Files\\zabbix_agentd_64.exe --config c:\\Program Files\\zabbix_agentd.conf --install"',
            }
```

Syntax is ok, but I get

> 'c:/Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command

I tried also `command => 'C:\\windows\system32\cmd.exe /c "c:\Program Files\zabbix_agentd_64.exe --config c:\Program Files\zabbix_agentd.conf --install"'` and `command => 'C:\\windows\system32\cmd.exe /c "c:\\Program/Files\\zabbix_agentd_64.exe --config c:\\Program/Files\\zabbix_agentd.conf --install"'`
 but it says syntax error (rightly in fact). Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puppet (probably the Ruby underneath, actually) is splitting your command string into words without regard to the internal quotes.  I don't think there is anything you can do to prevent that, but there is [a related issue in Puppet's bug tracker](https://tickets.puppetlabs.com/browse/PUP-3142).  You could consider commenting on / voting up that issue.  It *should* be possible to specify the command to the Exec in word-split form, as an array, which would provide a solution for your problem.

I see two possible alternatives to get it working now:

- Use the 8.3 name for the directory (see [how to get DOS path instead of Windows path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4051088/how-to-get-dos-path-instead-of-windows-path)).  This may be tricky, because I don't think the 8.3 path is uniquely determined by the file name alone -- it may be affected by the names of sibling files and directories.
- Specify a PATH for the Exec by which the desired executable can be found, and run it by its simple name.

Comment: Thank you for your replay John. DOS path works, but specifying a path for exec doesn't, I've tried it before. Writing manifests in Puppet on Windows I've descovered a lot of bugs, this is very ragged tool on this OS... Interesting is that using Windows path for directories with spaces in eg. file or service resources works perfectly.