# JAVA_HOME variable not setting in Windows

Tags: java, java-home

I've downloaded jdk9 and Java is installed in the following location.

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-9
```

and I'm trying to set up the JAVA_HOME variable under environment variables.

I've created a system variable

[image]

And I checked JAVA_HOME variable value in command as

[image]

But still it doesnt show the path of it. I've followed the other questions about this in stack. But nothing helped me. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: 1/ I'm pretty sure the space in "Program files" is an issue (use dos path) 2/ you need to restart the command prompt **after** you set some environment variable

Comment: @RC.What do u mean by (use dos path) ?

Comment: ...3. I am a little doubtful the complete path might just be like ....jdk-9/bin

Comment: @nullpointer, it should be C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-9
 or C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-9\bin

Comment: @RC. Yes it shows now after restarting command prompt. Kudos.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4051088/how-to-get-dos-path-instead-of-windows-path

Answer (score 0):

I restarted command prompt and it show me as below

[image]