# How to resolve error while using 'nvm use' command on windows

Tags: nvm

I installed node on my system. I also installed nvm. But when I am trying to use particular version, I am getting error as shown in image:

[click on this to view image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kcITS.png)

Please help me with this.

Comment: There  is a similar question here:https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows/issues/168

Answer (score 0):

It's because there's a space in your username. To fix it, you may use old-DOS style. To get it, open command line, go to folder `C:\Prithvi M` and execute command `for %I in (.) do echo %~sI`

```
C:\Prithvi M>for %I in (.) do echo %~sI
C:\Users\PRITHV~1
```

Having it, you may update 'root' attribute in your settings.xml (by default it's in your %homepath%\AppData\Roaming\nvm), to the old DOS-style.

example:

```
 root: C:\Users\PRITHV~1\AppData\Roaming\nvm
```

[1] [Get DOS path instead of Windows path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4051088/get-dos-path-instead-of-windows-path)

Comment: I copied and pasted what you have told(root: C:\Users\PRITHV~1\AppData\Roaming\nvm) in settings.txt. But it is saying that the path mentioned does'nt exist.

Comment: In console, go to folder C:\Users\Prithvi M, and execute command: for %I in (.) do echo %~sI     It will give you the exact DOS-style path

Comment: The command is showing the same original path.It isn't like any DOS style.

Comment: What is the result of `for %I in (.) do echo %~sI` on your computer?

Comment: C:\Users\Prithvi M>echo C:\Users\Prithvi M. Next line had again  C:\Users\Prithvi M

Comment: Please, in command line, go to directory `C:\Users`. What returns command `dir /x` ?

Comment: List of directories are displayed( . , .. , Prithvi M, Public) with dir \x command. It is still not showing dos path

Comment: On the screenshot https://i.imgur.com/nHCTw1m.png, you can see "short name" of a folder **Prithvi M** in blue circle. If you don't see it, then you may have **8dot3 names** disabled. To enable it, follow: https://digitalsupport.ge.com/en_US/Article/Is-Windows-8-3-File-Naming-Enabled-How-Do-I-Enable-8-3-File-Naming-If-It-Is-Not