I can't get pass the welcome page in android studio
It just say missing sdk and i downloaded it but it just not accepting it for a reason and when i follow tutorials they would have other options and i only have one like this image:

I tried the java jdk and the same result

As it says in the screenshot, do not use a path with whitespace. More generally, it looks like you have a network or permissions problem. It is hard to say without knowing much more about your configuration. Could you try to update the question with more details about what you did - exact steps to allow reproduction, and what you see in any logs, command line.

Well what exaclty should it show i used vpn and reinstalled it i downloaded the sdk from the web it just not accepting it

Go into a Windows DOS session type dir c:\Users /x (ref https://stackoverflow.com/q/4051088/1847378).  The "/x" will give you the short name which I am guessing will be something like Frankl~1 then use this short form of file name as the location C:\Users\Frankl~1\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk.  See if this helps
